# Selecting a sub-list with an associated string value

Tags: c#, linq

Assume I have the following:

```
public class ClassA
{
    public string Description {get;set;}
    public List<Product> Products {get;set;}
}

public class ClassB
{
    public string Description {get;set;}
    public Product SingleProduct {get;set;}
}

public class ClassC
{
    public List<ClassA> ListOfAs {get;set;}
    public List<ClassB> BreakDownListOfAs()
    {
        // This is the critical point
    }
}
```

At the marked critical point, I want to return a list of `ClassB` instances created from examining `ListOfAs` and decomposing it such that each instance of `ClassB` has a single product and the `Description` from the `ClassA` instance in which that `Product` resides.

Example, if I have:

```
var ListOfAs = new List<ClassA> {
    new ClassA {
        Description = "foo",
        Products = new List<Product> { p1, p2 }
    },
    new ClassA {
        Description = "bar",
        Products = new List<Product> { p3, p4 }
    }
};
```

Then the return value of `ClassC.BreakDownListOfAs()` should match:

```
new List<ClassB> {
    new ClassB { Description = "foo", Product = p1 },
    new ClassB { Description = "foo", Product = p2 },
    new ClassB { Description = "bar", Product = p3 },
    new ClassB { Description = "bar", Product = p4 },
}
```

I know I'd normally use `.SelectMany()` for projecting the sub-list, but I can't work out how to achieve the composition of the projected sub-elements with the string from the parent object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a LINQ method chain, it would look like this:

```
return ListOfAs
    .SelectMany(a => a.Products,
                (a, p) => new ClassB
                                {
                                    Description = a.Description,
                                    SingleProduct = p
                                })
    .ToList();
```

The trick is to create the object in the result selector using both the description from the ClassA instance and the Product from ClassA's list.

Comment: Aha, I didn't know about the .SelectMany(collectionSelector, resultSelector) overload. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

With LINQ syntax it's quite simple:

```
var query = from a in listOfAs
            from p in a.Products
            select new ClassB
            {
                Description = a.Description,
                SingleProduct = p
            };

var result = query.ToList();
```

Comment: Also spot on, though I prefer the chained syntax.

Answer (score 1):

```
IEnumerable<ClassB> breakdown =
    ListOfAs.Select(a => a.Products.Select(
                         p => new ClassB { Description = a.Description,
                                           SingleProduct = p }))
    .SelectMany(b => b);
```

Comment: Less keen on the nested .Select() segments in terms of readability, but is correct.

Comment: @MattSach Yes, Fls'Zen's answer is cleaner.